# Failed to connect Salesforce via c#

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I am trying to connect Salesforce api via C#. I have reset the security token and added it to the my password then i tried to connect. But login is failed. What am i doing wrong ? Any help would be appriciated.

Login function:

```
        public void sForceLogin(String userName, String password)
        {
            try
            {
                currentLoginResult = sForce.login(userName, password);
            }
            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception has been catched:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Main:

```
        SForceTest sft = new SForceTest();
        sft.sForceLogin("example@example.com", "password+securitytoken");
```

Comment: What error message do you get back? If you are connecting to a sandbox you will need to change the URL to test.Salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to login into salesforce.

> ```
>             using (SforceService service = new SforceService())
>             {
>                 LoginResult loginResult = 
>                 service.login(username, String.Concat(password, securityToken));
>                 this.SessionID = loginResult.sessionId;
>                 this.ServerUrl = loginResult.serverUrl;
>             }
> ```

Salesforce login api requires username, password and the security token.